# Why was the Deville process of Alumina production given up in favor of the Bayer process?

Tags: reaction-mechanism, history-of-chemistry

I guess this is a sort of historical question. The DeVille process seems fairly simple. Does anybody know the history or practical reasons for the switch?

Comment: The reason has to be cost. I have no specific knowledge of either process but looking at the DeVille process https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deville_process and the Bayer process https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bayer_process I can see that the Deville process uses an extra calcination step and bubbles carbon dioxide. Neither process seems to adequately deal with the process waste.

Comment: I think  the DeVille would produce waste with a lower pH.

Comment: This might have been a better fit on [hsm.se].

Comment: Related: [When is Serpeck's process preferred over Bayer's process?](http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/30889/7951)

Comment: [This](https://www.cairn.info/article.php?ID_ARTICLE=CHA_051_0042&DocId=271820&hits=9413+8759+8525+8440+8288+13+#page_header) looks like a promising source. I think you may have to buy it though if you want to read it.

Comment: @bon I should have been searching in french It is so obvious. Thank you so much.

Comment: I suspect the problem is that the differential step between the two processes involve calcination at high temperature for Deville vs. heating with sodium hydroxide at relatively lower temperature for Bayer. That's a huge energy and cost savings.

Comment: @GeoffHutchison Apparently both processes originally used CO2 bubbling and reclamation of the  Na2CO3 the modern Bayer process as I understand  it skips this step.

Answer (score 1):

The product of the Bayer process is purer than that of the Deville process.

Trevor I Williams, *Aluminium: latecomer to the metal industry*, Endeavour, Volume 17, Issue 2, 1993, Pages 89-93